# Cannot get current ID of an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to get the current ID of an item in table, but when i click the button Purchase and console.dir , it shows only the first element. I tried to console.dir the this.id and console shows me nothing

```
    function listProducts() {
    $('#shopProducts').empty();

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "appdata/" + kinveyAppKey + "/products",
        headers: getKinveyUserAuthHeaders(),
        success: loadProductsSuccess,
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
    // Load Products Success
    function loadProductsSuccess(products) {
        let table = $(`
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>`);
        let tr = $('<tr>');
        for (let product of products) {
            let tr = $('<tr>');
            displayTableRow(tr, product);
            tr.appendTo(table);
        }
        tr.appendTo(table);
        $('#shopProducts').append(table);
    }
    function displayTableRow(tr, product) {
        let links = [];
        let purchaseLink;
        purchaseLink = $("<button>Purchase</button>").click(function () {
            let currentPurchaseItem = $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: kinveyBaseUrl + "appdata/" + kinveyAppKey + "/products/" + this.id,
                headers: getKinveyUserAuthHeaders(),
                error: handleAjaxError
            });
            //showMenuCartView();
            //listMyCartProducts();
            console.dir(currentPurchaseItem);
            console.dir(this.id);
        });
        links.push(purchaseLink);
        tr.append(
            $("<td>").text(product.name),
            $("<td>").text(product.description),
            $("<td>").text(product.price),
            $("<td>").append(links)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ``this.id`` in the button's click event refers to the button - which has no id.

Comment: please make sure the button you target in your selector actually has an id.

Comment: How can i add id, so the program will work correctly ?

Comment: you are passing the product into the function, so a product.id or the related name you are using in the product structure should do the job

Comment: The task is to get the current id of the item in the collection.

Comment: could you share the part of html that this code is using?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wq9VeLFR

Comment: there is no `<button>Purchase</button>` in the html, also if the button you're talking about contains an id(which probably is because you want to get the id), you should use `$( "button:contains('Purchase')" )` instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `product.id` instead of `this.id`.

```
function displayTableRow(tr, product) {
    let links = [];
    let purchaseLink;
    purchaseLink = $("<button>Purchase</button>").click(function () {
        let currentPurchaseItem = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: kinveyBaseUrl + "appdata/" + kinveyAppKey + "/products/" + product.id,
            headers: getKinveyUserAuthHeaders(),
            error: handleAjaxError
        });
        //showMenuCartView();
        //listMyCartProducts();
        console.dir(currentPurchaseItem);
        console.dir(product.id);
    });
    links.push(purchaseLink);
    tr.append(
        $("<td>").text(product.name),
        $("<td>").text(product.description),
        $("<td>").text(product.price),
        $("<td>").append(links)
    );
}
```

As people has commented, seeing the payload of the ajax request will help.

Comment: I tried this and when i clicked on the button, i see console errors like: Request Method:GET
        Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: I really don't know which URL you are supposed to get. Can you show an example?

Comment: that 404 code means that it could not find the specified file, make sure the url in the ajax request is correct and points to a file.